# For loop for pooling fitted models

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm a bit of a beginner in R so would like to ask for some assistance.

I'm trying to use a for loop to iterate through my imputed fitted models in order to add some efficiency in pooling the models and afterwards computing the Rsquared for the models.

```
# Model with all Trust variables

fits_mod1 <- lm.mids(Trust ~  Tr_Family + Tr_Neighborhood + Tr_Personally
                     + Tr_Initial + Tr_Nationality, data = miceOut3)

# Model with all Trust + Discriminatory attitudes variables

fits_mod2 <- lm.mids(Trust ~  Tr_Family + Tr_Neighborhood + Tr_Personally
                     + Tr_Initial + Tr_Nationality
                     + Racism_neighborhood + Homosexuality, data = miceOut3)

# Model with all Trust + Police variables

fits_mod3 <- lm.mids(Trust ~  Tr_Family + Tr_Neighborhood + Tr_Personally
                     + Tr_Initial + Tr_Nationality 
                     + Confidence_police + Interfere_police, data = miceOut3)

# Model with all Trust + Happiness variables

fits_mod4 <- lm.mids(Trust ~ Tr_Family + Tr_Neighborhood + Tr_Personally
                     + Tr_Initial + Tr_Nationality
                     + Satisfaction + Feeling_happy, data = miceOut3)

# Model with all Trust + Danger variables

fits_mod5 <- lm.mids(Trust ~ Tr_Family + Tr_Neighborhood + Tr_Personally
                     + Tr_Initial + Tr_Nationality
                     + Violence + Avoid_danger, data = miceOut3)

# Model with all Trust + Control and Advantage variables

fits_mod6 <- lm.mids(Trust ~ Tr_Family + Tr_Neighborhood + Tr_Personally
                     + Tr_Initial + Tr_Nationality
                     + Adv_Taken + Control_life 
                     + Wealth_accumulation, data = miceOut3)

## Pool the fitted models:
poolFit1 <- pool(fits_mod1)
poolFit2 <- pool(fits_mod2)
poolFit3 <- pool(fits_mod3)
poolFit4 <- pool(fits_mod4)
poolFit5 <- pool(fits_mod5)
poolFit6 <- pool(fits_mod6)

## Compute the pooled R^2:
pool.r.squared(fits_mod1)
pool.r.squared(fits_mod2)
pool.r.squared(fits_mod3)
pool.r.squared(fits_mod4)
pool.r.squared(fits_mod5)
pool.r.squared(fits_mod6)

# select the model with highest rsquared 
pool.r.squared(fits_mod2)[1] - pool.r.squared(fits_mod1)[1]
```

My intention is to have the 'poolFit' per 'fits_model' within the range of 1:6 (for the 6 models) instead of having to make them manually.

Thanks!!

Comment: How did you create all those `fits_mod*` objects in the first place? Having a bunch of global variables with indexes in their name is a clue you might not be doing things in the the most R-like way. It's better to keep related data in a list. Then you can easily apply a function over that list without the need for an explicit loop.

Comment: Hi, MrFlick, I added the code which made the fits_mod objects. As you mentioned, I was approaching it with a "Python" kind of mindset, which really doesn't work for R. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `ls()` and then `get`. Assuming you have the fitted models in your workspace already, called `fits_mod1`, `fits_mod2`, `fits_mod3` etc.

```
fits_mods <- ls(pattern="^fits_mod\\d+")
fits_mods
# [1] "fits_mod1" "fits_mod2" "fits_mod3"

get(fits_mod[1]) # This shows the results.

poolFits <- list()
for(i in 1:3) {
  poolFits[[i]] <- pool(get(fits_mod[i]))
}

poolFits # show them all

# select the model with highest r-squared 
pool.r.squared(get(fits_mods[2]))[1] - pool.r.squared(get(fits_mods[1]))[1]
```

Comment: Hi Edward. This is exactly what I was looking for. I was approaching the problem with a different mindset, but your response really helped clarify how to approach working with for-loops and multiple objects in R. Much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

A more R-like way to do this would be something like this. Store your different formuals in a list, and then use `lapply` over the list to fit and summarize your models.

```
models <- list(
  Trust ~  Tr_Family + Tr_Neighborhood + Tr_Personally 
                     + Tr_Initial + Tr_Nationality,
  Trust ~  Tr_Family + Tr_Neighborhood + Tr_Personally
                     + Tr_Initial + Tr_Nationality
                     + Racism_neighborhood + Homosexuality,
  Trust ~  Tr_Family + Tr_Neighborhood + Tr_Personally
                     + Tr_Initial + Tr_Nationality 
                     + Confidence_police + Interfere_police,
  Trust ~ Tr_Family + Tr_Neighborhood + Tr_Personally
                     + Tr_Initial + Tr_Nationality
                     + Satisfaction + Feeling_happy,
  Trust ~ Tr_Family + Tr_Neighborhood + Tr_Personally
                     + Tr_Initial + Tr_Nationality
                     + Violence + Avoid_danger,
  Trust ~ Tr_Family + Tr_Neighborhood + Tr_Personally
                     + Tr_Initial + Tr_Nationality
                     + Adv_Taken + Control_life 
                     + Wealth_accumulation)

fits <- lapply(models, lm.mids, data=miceOut3)
pools <- lapply(fits, pool)
poolR2 <- lapply(fits, pool.r.squared)
```

Can you get get individual fits with `fits[[1]]`, `fits[[2]]`, etc

Comment: When I try using the code you mentioned it returns:

'> fits <- lapply(models, data=miceOut3)'
'Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default'

Maybe it helps to add that miceOut3 is a mids object for an imputed dataset?

Comment: I had a mistake that I’ve now fixed. I forgot to pass the `lm.mids` function to the `lapply`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried adding the function to it but forgot to remove the () in `lm.mids()` in the `lapply` so it gave me errors. Thanks a lot for your time!